# Performance of MPI+OpenMP code vs OpenMP Matrix Multiplication Code?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, matrix-multiplication, openmpi

I am running the code with MPI and each processor executing multithreading using OpenMp and other one is OpenMP parallel code, the performance worsens with array matrix size being 500 for MPI but I am able to find the results for matrix size being very large like 1000 which is not possible with just OpenMP, I am wondering whether it should always be the case that the performance of OpenMP with MPI would be better? or it can be the way it is in my use case.

Comment: Why don't you use a parallel math library for matrix multiplication? It is well optimized, you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Actually that is part of an assessment for the university, which requires to do everything at a very low level , that's why can not use the libraries.

Comment: A 1000 by 1000 matrix is tiny though, MPI for matrix multiplication makes sense when your matrices are much larger.